# Found 2 elements with non-unique id (#_ajax_nonce) and (#_wpnonce)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, nonce

I am developing custom theme from scratch and creates a custom post type and getting this warning while editing custom post type. I also design custom Meta box with two input fields and using nonce in it. Any help removing these warning?[image: I am developing custom theme from scratch and creates a custom post type and getting this warning while editing custom post type. I also design custom Meta box with two input fields and using nonce in it. Any help removing these warning?]

Here is code of custom metabox in functions.php

```php
//Custom Metabox

function register_book_meta_box(){
    add_meta_box('book_meta_box_id', 'Book Detail','design_book_meta_box','books','advanced','high');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes','register_book_meta_box');

function design_book_meta_box($post){
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__),'book_cpt_nonce')
    ?>
        <div>
            <label for="book-author">Author Name&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" name="book-author" placeholder="Author Name" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'book-author-key', true );?>">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="year">Published Year</label>
            <input type="number" id="year" name="year" min="1455" max="2020" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'book-year-key', true );?>">
            <span id="errorMsg" style="display:none;">Published Year Must be range from 1455 - 2020</span>
        </div>

    <?php
}
function save_book_meta_data($post_id)
{
    if(!isset($_POST['book_cpt_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['book_cpt_nonce'],basename(__FILE__))){
        return $post_id;
    }
    if (array_key_exists('book-author', $_POST)) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id,'book-author-key', $_POST['book-author']
        );
    }
    if (array_key_exists('year', $_POST)) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id,'book-year-key', $_POST['year']
        );
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_book_meta_data');
```

Comment: If they're duplicate IDs then something must be loading twice.  Neither of those IDs in the screenshot are generated by your code though.  Why are you checking for `if( array_exists() )` instead of `if( get_post_meta( 'year', $post->ID, false )`?

If you're checking for an array because you're generating multiple fields automatically and saving them to an array, then those fields may be the cause of duplicate IDs, although I don't see that in your code.  Want me to post how I would do the save as an answer and you can see if that helps?

Comment: @TonyDjukic Sure that would help

Comment: Done.  I honestly don't know if change will remove those errors and most likely won't... ...but it's worth a try.  Did you check the source of the edit page and see where the duplicate IDs are sitting?  Are they even in your meta boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Ali, as mentioned in the comments here's the method I'd use to save.  As you can see, it sets out the assorted fields and then runs the save process a single time, rather than setting the logic over and over for each field.

```
function save_book_meta_data( $post_id ) {
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        if( !isset( $_POST['book_cpt_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['book_cpt_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        $ali_book_meta['book-author-key']       = esc_textarea( $_POST['book-author-key'] );
        $ali_book_meta['book-year-key']         = esc_textarea( $_POST['book-year-key'] );
        foreach( $ali_book_meta as $key => $value ) :
            if( 'revision' === $post->post_type ) {
                return;
            }
            if( get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, false ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value );
            } else {
                add_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value);
            }
            if( !$value ) {
                delete_post_meta( $post_id, $key );
            }
        endforeach;
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_book_meta_data', 1, 2 );
```

I don't know if that addresses your actual issue but you could give it a try and see what happens.

It does ensure that only users with edit capabilities can make changes and avoids updating revisions because they shouldn't be updated, otherwise they wouldn't be revisions, they'd just be clones.

Comment: thanks for the help but unfortunately this code changes nothing

Comment: Did you check through the source and see where the duplicates are showing up?

Comment: I inspect element my meta box fields and check nonce value which is different from warnings nonce value

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, from what I can tell, it doesn't look as though the code you posted is the source of the duplicates.  I'm suggesting you check the source of the entire admin page and see if you can locate where specifically the duplicates are occurring and try to trace back from there.

Comment: it appears on add new and edit post screen On both wordpress default post and custom post type

Comment: I meant where specifically in the code does it appear.  You show the alerts, but not where in the source of those pages the code appears.  This could be a plugin conflict or an issue generated by some other aspect of your code, but the code in your question shouldn't be causing those errors.

Comment: I use this code in functions.php if that you you are asking?

Comment: No.  I was talking about viewing the source code, using developer tools in your browser, and running a FIND/SEARCH to see where the duplicate IDs show up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115132/discussion-between-ali-mirza-and-tony-djukic).